# ImportError: DLL load failed with PyQT5 when called from QT C++ Process call

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt5

I am trying to start a Python script from QT, in this Python Script I load PyQt5.
When I execute the  Python script from the command shell there is no problem, neither their is a problem when I start it within Spyder.

The start of the Python script from QT looks like this:

```
    QString command("python");
    QStringList params = QStringList() << "../../FAAAG/Python/SimpleResNet50.py";
    QProcess *process = new QProcess();
    if(process->startDetached(command,params,absPath))
        qDebug() << "successfull start";
    else
        qDebug() << "could not start python thread";
    process->waitForFinished(-1);
    process->close();
```

And in the python script I simply import PyQt like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSharedMemory,QBuffer
```

If I execute the C++ Program I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../FAAAG/Python/SimpleResNet50.py", line 18, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QSharedMemory,QBuffer
ImportError: DLL load failed:
```

If I call the Python script with the command that is provided to the startDetached function inside the Debug folder the execution works fine. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hard to tell where exactly the problem lies, but that 'DLL load failed' essentially means that a required dll is not in the PATH. In other words: the environment variable PATH is not setup correctly when you execute the C++ program. So solution is to make it correct and you'll first have to figure out what 'correct' is, i.e. print the PATH when in Spyder or so, and figure out how it gets that and/or out why the 'execute the C++ Program' part does not get that.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, but how can they be different if I only have one python version and are calling python as a new process? Is QProcess dependent on the Path variable set in QT Creator?

Comment: That's one possibility yes. E.g. suppose if you start QtCreator that it actually launches a batch file in with it modifies the PATH, then dependent processes (i.e. your exe) might inherit that.